# Flask is not getting application specific headers added through javascript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, flask

I am adding application specific headers in my GET request. I am able to view the header in my Chrome's developer console. So it seems they are being sent to the server.

The header is chart_type

[image]

But, when I try to access the headers in my flask application it, is missing from request.headers

The output of request.headers is below:

```
X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1
Host: localhost
X-Nginx-Proxy: true
Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Sec-Ch-Ua: "Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "macOS"
Accept: */*
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: http://localhost:8080/stock-market-pattern-modelling/quote?symbol=AAPL
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

Comment: Does it work when you use something like postman to call your endpoint with a custom header? Also, what code do you use to fetch the headers? Is your request rerouted before it ends up in Flask?

Comment: Good Point. I am using NGINX reverse proxy. I will check into it right now

Comment: Can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74798000/how-may-i-forward-a-non-standard-application-specific-header-from-nginx-to-my-ap

Comment: It seems @codeape already answered this question. It was indeed the underscores in the headernames. Learnt something new today.

Answer (score 6):

While underscores are allowed in header names, some server implementations silently drop headers with underscores in the name.

For instance Nginx with the default configuration will ignore headers with underscore in the name (see [`underscores_in_headers`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers) and [`ignore_invalid_headers`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#ignore_invalid_headers) documentation).

I therefore suggest that you try the header name `Chart-Type` instead of `chart_type`.

Comment: Earlier mine used to work with underscores but all of a sudden stopped working. Your solution fixed my issue.