# How may I forward a non standard application specific header from nginx to my application server?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, wsgi

I have not been able to pass an application specific header to my application that is running on uWSGI and Flask

This is from my nginx.conf

```
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass_request_headers on;
                proxy_set_header $HTTP_Chart-Type $http_chart_type;
        }
```

These are my headers from chrome:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: no-cache
chart_type: line
```

I am trying to pass the chart_type header to my backend.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The default value of `proxy_pass_request_headers` is `on`, so there should be no need to explicitly set it (unless it is turned off in the config somewhere and that has an effect on your configuration).

With the default setting (`on`), Nginx passes all headers to the backend, so you don't need any special configuration to pass a custom header (assuming your `http_chart_type` is a custom header).

Your problems passing the `http_chart_type` header from Nginx to the backend is likely related to Nginx by default not allowing header names with underscore. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74798560/3571 .

Comment: Thank You. Thank You. Thank You. It was the underscores in the header name